# Displaying image retrieved from google drive

Tags: php, html, laravel

i successfully set up my connection to google drive and saved an image on it. now i want to retrieve it in my blade view. unfortunately, i cannot put the response in `src` of the `<img>` tag, because it returns image itself and not a path to it.

i tried using Intervention Image package, but when i used the `make()` method, i inspected it and it still had no `path` attribute, so i assume there is not any, to be made this easily. can i display the image without it having a `path`? or how do i create a temporary path for the returned image, if it is possible, in one line?

i have the image data in this collection

```
$storage = collect(\Storage::cloud()->listContents($this->getGoogleFolderId(), false));
```

my attempts to gather as much information as possible:

```
dd($storage->where('name', $breakdowns->first()->image->path025)->first());
```

returns:

```
array:10 [▼
  "name" => "2020-10-18-16-46-25-lq.jpg"
  "type" => "file"
  "path" => "1aCS7hRWQWjVwLdF_nn5NKTKJZUbRyq2M/1qTUzjvN6qQBHpGKvN1Xic4SYsVsEgskR"
  "filename" => "2020-10-18-16-46-25-lq"
  "extension" => "jpg"
  "timestamp" => 1603032376
  "mimetype" => "image/jpeg"
  "size" => 59213
  "dirname" => "1aCS7hRWQWjVwLdF_nn5NKTKJZUbRyq2M"
  "basename" => "1qTUzjvN6qQBHpGKvN1Xic4SYsVsEgskR"
]
```

and this:

```
dd(\IImage::make(\Storage::disk('google')->get($storage->where('name', $breakdowns->first()->image->path025)->first()['path'])));
```

returns:

```
Intervention\Image\Image {#1562 ▼
  #driver: Intervention\Image\Gd\Driver {#1555 ▼
    +decoder: Intervention\Image\Gd\Decoder {#1567 ▼
      -data: null
    }
    +encoder: Intervention\Image\Gd\Encoder {#1561 ▼
      +result: null
      +image: null
      +format: null
      +quality: null
    }
  }
  #core: gd resource @747 ▼
    size: "1079x1758"
    trueColor: true
  }
  #backups: []
  +encoded: ""
  +mime: "image/jpeg"
  +dirname: null
  +basename: null
  +extension: null
  +filename: null
}
```

Comment: Do you want to serve the image straight from google cloud or do you want to download it to your server then display it?

Comment: only display it if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd approach your problem.
The image should already be the format you need it to be.

**Controller**

```
public function getImage($path)
{
    $filePath = $storage->where('name', $path)->first();

    if(isset($filePath->id)) {
        $disk = Storage::disk('google');
        $image = $disk->get($filePath->{THE ATTRIBUTE ON THAT MODEL WHICH HAS THE GOOGLE PATH});

        return response($image)->header('Content-Type', 'image/png');
    }
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/dynamic-image/{path}', 'ImageController@getImage');
```

**Blade**

```
<img src="/dynamic-image/{{$bd->image->path025}}">
```

Comment: i tried to inline it in blade like this, does not work so far ```<img src="{{ response(Storage::disk('google')->get($storage->where('name', $bd->image->path025)->first()['path']))->header('Content-Type', 'image/png') }}" alt="obrazok" height="50">```

Comment: You cannot do that, you need a request to go and pickup this image, I'll edit my answer

Comment: you should be able to edit the `$storage` part to work as you're using it, mine is just an example and of course the variable isn't set anywhere

Comment: i will try it first thing in the morning, so i can check your answer as correct. thank you.